# How to get plain text from p:editor on server side?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have an editor of primefaces. I want to have its html string on server side as well as plain string on server side. I have tried following:

```
<p:inputTextarea id="manualCommentsText" cols="65" rows="16"
                    value="#{abean.commentTxt}" style="display:none;"/>

<p:editor widgetVar="cComments" id="manualComments" value="#{abean.comment}"/>

<p:commandButton id="submitBtn" value="Confirm"
    action="#{abean.confirmComments}" onclick="PF('cComments').selectAll();document.getElementById('manualCommentsText').value=PF('cComments').getSelectedText();"
    style="float:right;" />
```

On button click, I get the plain text from editor using its Client API and set it in hidden input text area. In the bean action method of the button, I still receive null plain text. I think getSelectedText() method of the editor is not working. However, it works when I use it in developer tools.

```
public void confirmComments() {
    System.out.println("comment plain: " + this.commentTxt);
}
```

The html comment is coming fine in the bean. How to get and send plain text from primefaces editor to the backing bean?

Primefaces version: 5.2.24
JDK version: 8

Comment: 1: For creating plain text, I would not rely on the client (prone to hacking). Do an unhtmlify on the server side.2: Tried PF 7.0? 3: Try using onblur on the editor. Setting values in the click on commandButton might be too late

Comment: I am restricted to use PF 5.2.24. If I unhtmlify on server side, there is chance that user has entered < or > symbols similar to something like html tags. then those will also be removed

Comment: You can always **try** if a newer version works. Not to difficult if yo uhave a [mcve]. And no, most likely < and > are received as &lt; and &gt;

Comment: I had the same problem. To solve it I used [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/) (a html parser)